# Variable being passed not making it to backend

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make a simple deletion from an array of objects. I'm passing the object's id to the backend, but when I output the parameter to the terminal, it just prints an empty array.

My **Angular** is passing the object to the server:

```
$scope.removeFavoriteRecipe = function(favorite){
    var deleteIt = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this recipe from your favorites?");
    if(deleteIt){
        console.log(favorite._id)
        $http.delete("/removeFavoriteRecipe/" + favorite._id)
        .then(function(returnData){
            if(returnData.data.err){
                $scope.err = returnData.data.err;
            }else{
                $scope.err = "";
                $window.location.reload();
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I'm using `server.delete("/removeFavoriteRecipe/:id",favRecipeController.removeFavoriteRecipe);` to pass it to the backend

**This is where I believe the hiccup happens.** Once it gets to the backend, the id is not in `req.params`:

```
var removeFavoriteRecipe = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params._id);
    if(req.user){
        userModel.User.update({_id: req.user._id}, {$pull :{favoriteRecipes: {_id: req.params._id}}}, function(err){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                res.send("success!");
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        var err = {err: "You are not logged in."};
        res.send(err);
    }
}
```

`console.log(favorite._id);` shows the id, but `console.log(req.params._id);` shows an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem: I should use `put` instead of `delete`, but also I was sending back `favorite._id` when I should have just sent `favorite`.

This is my new code:

**Angular:**

```
$scope.removeFavoriteRecipe = function(favorite){
    var deleteIt = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this recipe from your favorites?");
    if(deleteIt){
        console.log(favorite._id)
        $http.put("/removeFavoriteRecipe", favorite)
        .then(function(returnData){
            if(returnData.data.err){
                $scope.err = returnData.data.err;
            }else{
                $scope.err = "";
                $window.location.reload();
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Server:**

```
server.put("/removeFavoriteRecipe", favRecipeController.removeFavoriteRecipe);
```

**Node:**

```
var removeFavoriteRecipe = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body._id);
    if(req.user){
        userModel.User.update({_id: req.user._id}, {$pull :{favoriteRecipes: {_id: req.body._id}}}, function(err){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                res.send("success!");
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        var err = {err: "You are not logged in."};
        res.send(err);
    }
}
```

Special thanks to bstockwell for helping me get to my conclusion!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: `DELETE` doesn't allow for body data, so you can either change your request to a `PUT` and use the code below, or use the original code and get the id from the url.

Req.body isn't available immediately you need to add it to an string chuck by chuck and then create an object out of it once the stream ends:

```
var removeFavoriteRecipe = function(req, res){

    let data = "";
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      // append the current chunk of data to the fullBody variable
      data += chunk.toString();

    });

    if(req.user){
        req.on('end', function() {
            let body = JSON.parse(data)
            userModel.User.update({_id: req.user._id}, {$pull :{favoriteRecipes: {_id: body._id}}}, function(err){
                if(err){
                    res.send(err);
                }else{
                    res.send("success!");
                }
            }); 
        });

    }else{
        var err = {err: "You are not logged in."};
        res.send(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the code I currently have. I've used req.body on all of my other functions, and it had worked just fine.

Comment: Hmm. Are you using any modules like express? that would potentially change the way these things work. If you output console.log(req.body) instead of req.body._id does that also show undefined?

Comment: console.log(req.body) shows an empty array. I went back and reviewed a piece of my code that does a similar deletion, and I used req.params instead of req.body. It still shows req.params._id as being undefined.

Comment: Ok, actually, now that I'm looking into this further, `DELETE` doesn't allow for body data, so the node server is probably trashing whatever you send. You could use a put in it's place and the above code would work. But you might be better off getting the id from the url if that's all that you're sending.

Comment: That makes sense, but now I'm getting a bad request. I changed everything to put requests, but now it's telling me that there is a SyntaxError: Unexpected token 5

Comment: Figured it out was sending `favorite._id` instead of just `favorite`.